# How do I add a page to this zend project

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I've been assigned to this project that uses Zend Framework 1.12. I'm trying to add a page to the project but I seem to be missing something somewhere. The directory structure is a bit different than any example Zend project I have seen (no bootstrap dir).

-application

---controllers

------modules

---------------nopage

------------------------ IndexController.php

---model

---- a bunch of db files

---views

----templates (smarty tpl files)

---------------nopage

------------------------ nopage.tpl

---backend

----router.php

Here is my code for the router.php

```
$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controller/nopage', 'nopage');
$router = $controller -> getRouter();

$nopage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'nopage.html',
array('module' => 'nopage', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);

$router -> addRoute('nopage', $nopage);
```

Here is my IndexController code for nopage IndexController.php

```
<?php

/** Zend_Controller_Action */
Zend_Loader::loadClass('System_Controller_Action');


class Nopage_IndexController extends System_Controller_Action 
{   

public function indexAction() {

            $this -> smarty -> assign('PageBody', 'nopage/404.tpl');
            $this -> smarty -> assign('Title', 'PetIdMe - 404');
            $this -> smarty -> display('layouts/main.tpl');
    } 
}
```

and I get this error:

Invalid controller specified (index)

My code seems to follow the same structure and everything that all the other routes do, I have searched and searched to no avail on this. Would the knowledgeable and generous folks here at SO have any ideas here? If you need more information I would be glad to provide it. Thanks so much in advance for any insight into this.

EDIT SOME EXTRA CODE FROM THE ROUTER

```
$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controllers/lostandfound',      'lostandfound');

$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controllers/search', 'search');

$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controllers/orderstatus', 'orderstatus');

$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controllers/myaccount', 'myaccount');


$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controllers/giftcard', 'giftcard');

$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controller/nopage', 'nopage');



$router = $controller -> getRouter();


$nopage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
'nopage.html',
array('module' => 'nopage', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);

$router -> addRoute('nopage', $nopage);
//****************** Gift Card ************************************************************

$giftcard = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'giftcard.html',
array('module' => 'giftcard', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);
$router -> addRoute('giftcard', $giftcard);

$GiftCardsPages = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'admin/gift/page/(\d*)',
array('module'=>'admin', 'controller'=>'gift', 'action'=>'index'),
array(1  =>'page')
);
$router -> addRoute('GiftCardsPages', $GiftCardsPages);

//****************** SEARCH ***************************************************************
$topsearchserult = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'topsearchserult.html',
array('module'=>'search', 'controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'search'),
array(1  =>'page')
);
$router -> addRoute('topsearchserult', $topsearchserult);

//****************** MY ACCOUNT *********************************************************

$myaccount = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
'myaccount.html',
array('module' => 'myaccount', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
);
$router -> addRoute('myaccount', $myaccount);
```

AND SOME FROM OTHER IndexController PAGES:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('System_Controller_Action');

class News_IndexController extends System_Controller_Action {

public function init() {
    parent::init();
}

public function viewAction() {
    $new = $this -> News -> getNewById($this->_getParam('new_id'));
    $this->smarty->assign('new', $new);
    $this->smarty->assign('Title', $new['new_title']);
    $this->smarty->assign('PageBody', 'news/show_item.tpl');
    $this->smarty->display('layouts/main.tpl');
}

public function indexAction() {

    $page = $this->_hasParam('page')?((int)$this->_getParam('page')-1):0; 
    $items = $this->News->getNewsForPage($page);

    $this->smarty->assign('items', $items);
    $this->smarty->assign('Title', 'News items');
    $this->smarty->assign('page_num', $page+1);
    $this->smarty->assign('page_count', $this->News->getPagesCount());
    $this->smarty->assign('PageBody', 'news/index.tpl');
    $this->smarty->display('layouts/main.tpl');
}
```

AND ANOTHER

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('System_Controller_Action');
include_once ROOT . 'application/models/GiftCardsDb.php';
class GiftCard_IndexController extends System_Controller_Action 
{
private $giftcard;
 public function init() {
    $this->giftcard = new GiftCardDb();
    parent::init();
}

public function indexAction() {
    if($this->_hasParam('product_id')){
        $this -> smarty -> assign('giftcard_text', $this -> Content ->     getPageByLink('giftcard.html'));
        $this -> smarty -> assign('giftcard_agreement_text', $this -> Content -> getPageByLink('giftcard_agreement.html'));
        $this -> smarty -> assign('PageBody', 'giftcard/index.tpl');
        $this -> smarty -> assign('product_id', $this->_getParam('product_id'));
        $this -> smarty -> assign('Title', 'Pet Id Me - Gift Card');
        $this -> smarty -> display('layouts/main.tpl');
    } else {
        $this->_redirect("/");
    }
    }
```

Comment: In your $controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controller/nopage', 'nopage'); can u echo the VALUE of ROOT and let me know what you get?

Comment: The root path is correct, there are about 30 other '$controller -> addControllerDirectory(ROOT . 'application/controller/XXX', 'XXX');' in the router that work fine.

Comment: Can u paste any other example how you are setting routes for any other page. You must be having them right?

Comment: Edited to show more examples.

Comment: Why you using new Zend_Controller_Router_Route but other places it is new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex?

Comment: I was trying it, doesn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: Check my answer  does tht make sense.

Answer (score 0):

you add zend framework extra page some steps given

1.zend is MVC pattern

2.create view file name  and controller file name same name

example : view->save.phtml
controller:saveAction

3.you include database connection implement controller (or) call db method
  refer follow link
     http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Zend-Framework-Basic-Tutorial-P840.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is add this line

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('System_Controller_Action');
```

at the starting of your IndexController. i.e

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('System_Controller_Action');

class Nopage_IndexController extends System_Controller_Action 
{
```

Comment: It is there, just formatted in the example not showing as code.

Comment: Then can you try clearing your cache folder that resides in storage folder(i hope) may be when u add new configuration to routes u need your routes to not pick from cache. Not sure but give a try?

Comment: Im researching how to do this, If I change the controller in:        $nopage = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'nopage.html',
    array('module' => 'nopage', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')
    );

    $router -> addRoute('nopage', $nopage); to something else it changes the error. What else could be causing this?

Comment: Invalid controller specified (INSERT WHATEVER I CHANGE THE CONTROLLER ARRAY VALUE TO HERE)